# what happens to memory when reassign array in C#?

Tags: c#, arrays, memory

In the following code, what happens to the memory myArray initially pointed to once it's reassigned in the 2nd line?  Is that memory lost, or does the C# garbage collector take care of it?

```
static void Main(string[] args)
{
   double[] myArray = new Double[10];
   myArray = new Double[3];
}
```

As far as I've been reading, there's no way to explicitly free up the memory, so I'm hoping C# automatically does it.

Comment: _garbage collector will take care of it_

Comment: Data still remains in memory for a while. Because you don't have any pointer to that data anymore, GC will collect that space when necessary.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When your variable goes out of scope and the memory is no longer required then it becomes eligible for garbage collection.

MS explains all, as seen here:  https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa691138(v=vs.71).aspx

> C# employs automatic memory management, which frees developers from manually allocating and freeing the memory occupied by objects.
>
> Automatic memory management policies are implemented by a garbage
> collector. The memory management life cycle of an object is as
> follows:
>
> 1. When the object is created, memory is allocated for it, the constructor is run, and the object is considered live.
> 2. If the object, or any part of it, cannot be accessed by any possible continuation of execution, other than the running of
>    destructors, the object is considered no longer in use, and it becomes
>    eligible for destruction. The C# compiler and the garbage collector
>    may choose to analyze code to determine which references to an object
>    may be used in the future. For instance, if a local variable that is
>    in scope is the only existing reference to an object, but that local
>    variable is never referred to in any possible continuation of
>    execution from the current execution point in the procedure, the
>    garbage collector may (but is not required to) treat the object as no
>    longer in use.
> 3. Once the object is eligible for destruction, at some unspecified later time the destructor (Section 10.12) (if any) for the
>    object is run. Unless overridden by explicit calls, the destructor for
>    the object is run once only.
> 4. Once the destructor for an object is run, if that object, or any part of it, cannot be accessed by any possible continuation of
>    execution, including the running of destructors, the object is
>    considered inaccessible and the object becomes eligible for
>    collection.
> 5. Finally, at some time after the object becomes eligible for collection, the garbage collector frees the memory associated with
>    that object.

If you want to go into more detail then you can look here:  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/garbage-collection/index

or I'm sure you can also find some blogs on the topic.

Answer (score 3):

Of course, C# automatically releases memory that was associated with `myArray` prior to the assignment. This does not happen right away, but as soon as garbage collector realizes there are no remaining references to that `Double[10]` array object*, the memory allocated to the object gets reclaimed.

If you change your program slightly to create a second reference to the same array, like this

```
double[] myArray = new Double[10];
double[] myArray2 = myArray; // Second reference
myArray = new Double[3];
```

garbage collector would *not* release the object, as long as a reference to it remains accessible to your program.

* Sometimes your program finishes execution before garbage collector gets to complete its analysis. The memory still gets released, though.

Comment: _as soon as garbage collector realizes there are no remaining references_ .- depend on application size/using this can hapenned after application is closed

Comment: @Fabio That's fair. I added a footnote to mention this. Thanks!